# How to build a "services" BD with prices

Tags: mysql, database

Im currently building an interface with PHP and MYSQL with all my salon services and everything was fine till I had to add my waxing services:

When talking about waxing you can have every combination between these group:

```
Lips      
Chin      
Face      
Underarms      
Arms      
Eyebrows      
None of the above
```

Also one of these:

```
Half Leg      
Full Leg      
No Legs
```

And one of these:

```
Small Bikini      
Big Bikini      
Brasilian   
No Bikini
```

So, I was thinking on doing the first part on binary until I figure out that just on the first part I had 128 combinations, plus 3 different variations on the next group(Legs) and 4 more under the bikini area.... This makes a total of 2048 possible combinations?? so that means that I will have to fill a DB with 2048 different descriptions, prices and services codes(the most important column)

So This is when I know that im doing something wrong here(regarding the method) and I need your help to know how is this done from the BD point of view. After all I just need a service code that will allow me in the future to differentiate each service from the other one.

And if this is the real way of doing it, how or what do you use to generate the 2000+ rows with the data?

Thanks

Comment: None of these appeal to me.

Comment: Presumably you do bundles like 'any 3 for 10 dollars' or 'any 4 for 12 dollars'? It's pointless to try to price every possible combination. It would be meaningless to both your business and the customer.

Comment: I could do it but then I coudl hapeople taking just 2, or just 1 or maybe all of them. So Imo I think I still need a way of pricing each and also a reference code to that service, otherwise how am I going to know in 20 months why "Jane" paid 20 bucks? If I had the code (like 200101) I knew what Jane paid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you do this if you weren't using software? If a client came and asked for, say, eyebrows, arms, and full legs....

Would you say eyebrows are $3, arms are $6, and full legs are $10?

If so, you can create yourself a data base row for each particular service you offer, and allow your client to choose any combination of products.

This involves a many-to-many relationship between your client and your service tables. In RDMSs like MySQL, you'll need a `client` table, a `service` table, and a `client_service` table.  The third of those contains pairs of numbers, `client_id` and `service_id`, and perhaps a date.  If you want to know what services a certain client had yesterday, you could, for example, use a query like this

```
 select cs.service_time, c.name, s.service
   from client c
   join client_service cs ON c. client_id = cs.client_id
   join service ON cs.service_id = s.service_id
               AND DATE(cs.service_time) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  where c.name = 'Jane'
```

The point of the `client_service` table is to allow you to associate multiple clients with each service, and multiple services with each client. This is a far better software design choice than the combinations you mention, which will soon outnumber the hairs on your clients', umm, heads.

The user interface for this kind of table will present a list of the services you offer (the rows in your service table) with a checkbox next to each one.

As you wait on each client, you'll check the services you deliver.  Then your software will create a row in your client_service table for every check on the list.

If your `service` table contain a price for each service, you can retrieve those prices as follows.

```
 select DATE(cs.service_time), c.name, s.service, SUM(s.price) AS price
   from client c
   join client_service cs ON c. client_id = cs.client_id
   join service ON cs.service_id = s.service_id
               AND DATE(cs.service_time) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  where c.name = 'Jane'
  group by c.name, DATE(cs.service_time), s.service WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Nice answer! But is that a pre- or post-wax count

Comment: thanks Ollie but this is now what im looking for yet. My question was, how to build that client_service table.. Or how to build a DB that will allow me to know in the future if Jane paid for Legs and Bikini (total 10$) and not Legs and Arms (10$ too).

Comment: The words "now" and "not" have very different meanings, so I don't understand your comment very well. At any rate read my edit.